# Octave: For-Loop creates wrong variables

Tags: variables, for-loop, scanf, octave, fopen

I want to read parameters from a text file and summarise it to four variables. Because of that many parameters, I decided me to write a for-loop to automate it.

The problem is, that the loop only creates one variable with the wrong name "ans" instead "machnumber".
Here is my code, maybe you can see any failure:

```
function [machNumbers, weights, altitudes, specificRanges]=readsrm(myfilename)
myfilename = "parameterfile.txt"

  fid = fopen(myfilename,'r');
  fskipl(fid, 3);

  # read number of machnumber
  numMachNumber = fscanf(fid, "%i", 1)
  fscanf(fid, "%s", 5);
  machNumbers = fscanf(fid, "%f", numMachNumber);

  # read weights
  numWeights = fscanf(fid, "%i", 1);
  fscanf(fid, "%s", 5);
  weights = fscanf(fid, "%f", numWeights)

  # rad altitudes 
  numFl = fscanf(fid, "%i", 1)
  fscanf(fid, "%s", 5);
  altitudes = fscanf(fid, "%f", numFl)

  irrelevantValues = fscanf(fid, "%s", 7)

  for altitudes = 1:numFl
    for weights = 1:numWeights
      specificRanges(altitudes, weights, 1:numMachNumber) = fscanf(fid, "%f", numMachNumber);
    endfor
  endfor
  fclose(fid);
endfunction
```

And this is the text file:

```
SRMST     15112012 4


   26  MN       CV BI CV MACHNUMBER
    0.44    0.46    0.48    0.50    0.52    0.54    0.56    0.58
    0.60    0.62    0.64    0.66    0.68    0.70    0.71    0.72
    0.73    0.74    0.75    0.76    0.77    0.78    0.79    0.80
    0.81    0.82

   29  KG       LN BI LN WEIGHT
  39000.  40500.  42000.  43500.  45000.  46500.  48000.  49500.
  51000.  52500.  54000.  55500.  57000.  58500.  60000.  61500.
  63000.  64500.  66000.  67500.  69000.  70500.  72000.  73500.
  75000.  76500.  78000.  79500.  81000.

   24  FT       LN BI LN ALTITUDE
  18000.  19000.  20000.  21000.  22000.  23000.  24000.  25000.
  26000.  27000.  28000.  29000.  30000.  31000.  32000.  33000.
  34000.  35000.  36000.  37000.  38000.  39000.  40000.  41000.

18096  NMTO     LN BI LN SPECIFIC RANGE
  176.47  175.17  176.48  173.93  170.98  167.27  163.47  159.51
  155.33  151.18  147.02  142.67  138.02  133.25  131.67  131.67
```

I would welcome your help.

All the best,

Michael

Comment: How are you calling your function? Apparently you're calling your function without any output argument. `ans` is the variable to which the output is assigned when you don't explicitly mention any output argument

Comment: Aren't the variables in the box brackets the output arguments?

Comment: Yes but Octave cannot assume itself that you want those outputs and with those names.

Comment: So can you please tell me how I say Octave to write the parameters in the output variables with these names? :) Or I would welcome a link with a specific tutorial too.

Comment: Just write them as output arguments *when calling the function*. I am not familiar with any Octave tutorials. I would suggest [Getting Started with MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html) for learning basics